# Custom Taxonomy and tax_query Issue?

Tags: custom-post-type, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I am working on Plugin development and my plugin name is `plugindev`.I have a custom post type called `team`.I have a custom taxonomy `Team_Category` which is being registered by this code

```
/***************************taxonomy****************************/
add_action( 'init', 'create_team_taxonomies', 0 );
function create_team_taxonomies() {
    // Add new taxonomy, make it hierarchical (like categories)
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Team_Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Team_Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Team_Categories' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Team_Categories' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Team_Category' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Team_Category:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Team_Category' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Team_Category' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Team_Category' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Team_Category Name' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Team_Category' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => false,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'Team_Category' ),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'Team_Category', array( 'team' ), $args );
}
/****************************taxanomy end***********************************/
```

But when I use a tax_query in my WP_Query, I do  not get any  posts.
here is my code

```
<?php
$taxonomy_name = 'Team_Category';
$get_categories = get_terms($taxonomy_name);
$total_categories = count($get_categories);
// Loop through the obituaries:
for ($i = 0; $i < $total_categories; $i++) {
    ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <?php echo $category_name = $get_categories[$i]->name; ?>
        </div>
        <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'team',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'Team_Category', 
                    'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => $category_name,)
                )
         );

        $query = new WP_Query($args);

        if ($query->have_posts()) {
        while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();
            the_title();
        }
        }
        wp_reset_query(); ?>

    </div>

<?php }
```

It works perfectly without `tax_query`.I did lot of google but found no suitable result.Any solution to solve this problem .Any help would be highly  appreciated

Comment: post-status should not be post_status?

Comment: BTW, publish is the default value for post_status so it is no necessary to add it

Comment: @ThemesCreator I have removed `'post-status'=>'publish'` now but it has o effect on result

Comment: have you test to see if the variable $category_name has a  correct value?

Comment: @ ThemesCreator ya when i used `<?php echo $category_name = $get_categories[$i]->name; ?>` it gives there name as there were two name..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[register_taxonomy()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy)

> $taxonomy (string) (required) The name of the taxonomy. Name should
>   only contain lowercase letters and the underscore character, and not
>   be more than 32 characters long (database structure restriction).

change your taxonomy name from `Team_Category` to `team_category`

you should then be able to use argument like this

```
$arg = array(
    'post_type' => 'team', 
    'taxonomy' => 'team_category',
    'term' => 'term_name',
);

//using tax_query
$mytax = get_terms('your_taxonomy');
$arg = array(
    'post_type' => 'team', 
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'team_category',
            'field'    => 'slug', 
            'terms'    => 'term_slug', //you need to use slug not name $mytax[0]->slug; 

            #or 
            //'field'    => 'name', 
            //'terms'    => 'term_name', //you need to use term name $mytax[0]->name;

            #or 
            //'field'    => 'term_id', 
            //'terms'    => 'term_ID', //you need to use term ID $mytax[0]->term_id;
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: it works for me but I don't know why this code is not running `'tax_query' => array(array( 'taxonomy' => 'team_category',  'field' => 'slug', 'terms' =>$category_name))` even i have changed `Team_Category` to `team_category`

Comment: I edited my answer, you define the tax ```'field' => 'slug'``` but you seem to be adding the value of taxonomy name ```'terms' =>$category_name```

Comment: In my case it should be like this   `$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'team',
          
            'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'team_category',
            'field'    => 'slug', 
            'terms'    => $get_categories, //you need to use slug $mytax->slug; 
        ),
    ),
         );` but it gives me error

Comment: your ```$get_categories``` is a category name based on this ```$category_name = $get_categories[$i]->name;``` you can simply change this ```'field' => 'slug',``` to ```'field' => 'name',```  to use name instead of slug, or if you prefer to use slug, you can change ```$get_categories[$i]->name;``` to ```$get_categories[$i]->slug;``` whatever you define on ```'field'``` that's what you must provide

Answer (score 0):

WP_Query($nivelquery) and the loop will now print every post registered using my custom taxonomy in $terms, and order them by the meta_key 'salary'.

```
   $terms = get_terms('Team_Category',
        array(
            'orderby' => 'slug',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'hide_empty' => 1,
            'fields' => 'ids',

        ));

$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'vagas_tipo',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $terms,
       ),
    ),
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key' => 'salary',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```